# Why does the browser show the actual certificate and still mitmproxy is able to decrypt?

Tags: encryption, certificate, mitmproxy

I was trying out the latest 5.2 version of mitmproxy in Windows 10. The client was an Android 10 device and the browser was Brave. I noticed that the address bar details were showing the actual certificate names (like Digicert etc) but still, I was able to see the decrypted traffic in the web UI. How can that be possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbFYt.png)

Comment: I'm not sure that it actually does this, but mitmproxy could be copying all of the attributes of the server cert when it generates it's own on the fly. You should look at the chain, though. Who signed/issued the cert you're seeing? What is the root?

Comment: The chain points to Digicert Global Root G2 itself. However, I could see all the traffic getting decrypted from that site. When I tried the same thing with an older version of mitmproxy several months ago -  if I was able to see the decrypted traffic for a site, the certificate info would always display mitmproxy.

Comment: I would assume that this is a bug of the webbrowser. I had once seen something similar on Desktop Firefox when enabling HTTPS interception and reloading the web page. The certificate stayed the same (original) but actually used was mitm proxy cert.